# How to use TCPDF with FPDI in a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, fpdf, fpdi

I am using FPDI to generate PDFs from a template.pdf file in a Laravel 5 project, but I am having issues with UTF-8 names since FDPI does not support the encoding natively.

I did a lot of searching and [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) and [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) seem to be the most used solutions for this issue, though I cannot seem to successfully integrate any of them in my laravel application.

I have already referred to these links with no luck:

FPDI with tFPDF: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/legacy-v1/
FPDI with TCPDF: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/tcpdf-demo/

This is the PHP function I am using inside my laravel controller.

```
public static function generateCertificate($firstname, $fullname, $course_name, $level, $date, $output, $email = null, $certificate_link = null)
{

    $fullname = stripslashes($fullname);
    $fullname = 'Witaj świecie'; //Added to debug issue

    //Start PDF Generation
    $pdf = new \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();

    //Set Template
    $path = app()->publicpath().'/assets/templates/examination_level100_certificate.pdf';


    $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($path);
    $template  = $pdf->importPage(1);
    $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($template);

    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($template, null, null, null, null, true);

    //Add the fonts
    $pdf->AddFont('Myriad-pro', '', 'myriad-pro-regular.php');
    $pdf->AddFont('Myriad-pro-semibold', '', 'myriad-pro-semibold.php');

    //Set Title
    $pdf->SetTitle($fullname.' - '.str_replace(' - ', ' ', $course_name).' - Certicifate');

    //Add User Name
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 40);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(67, 156, 209);
    $pdf->SetY(164);
    $pdf->Cell(0, 20, $fullname, 0, 1, 'C');

    $pdf->Output('I', str_slug($fullname.'-'.$course_name).'.pdf', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is TCPDF/FPDF question which is used by FPDI (to cooperate with FPDI I recommend you FPDF instead of TCPDF)

First of all you need to add font that has your encoding. 
More: http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm

For example:

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.php');
$pdf->SetFont('DejaVu', '', 10, '', false);
```

Second,  In regard to FPDF library that is user by FPDI: There possible encodings:

```
cp1250 (Central Europe)
cp1251 (Cyrillic)
cp1252 (Western Europe)
cp1253 (Greek)
cp1254 (Turkish)
cp1255 (Hebrew)
cp1257 (Baltic)
cp1258 (Vietnamese)
cp874 (Thai)
ISO-8859-1 (Western Europe)
ISO-8859-2 (Central Europe)
ISO-8859-4 (Baltic)
ISO-8859-5 (Cyrillic)
ISO-8859-7 (Greek)
ISO-8859-9 (Turkish)
ISO-8859-11 (Thai)
ISO-8859-15 (Western Europe)
ISO-8859-16 (Central Europe)
KOI8-R (Russian)
KOI8-U (Ukrainian)
```

The string that was sent by me to pdf was in UTF-8 (I checked it by  mb_detect_encoding function) and there was need to convert on cp1250.

Third, just convert:

```
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1250', 'zazółcić gęślą jaźń');
```

Also useful: https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/manual/

Comment: FPDI already uses the FPDF library by default. I have already tried the iconv() solution but I get an exception when using names like 'Здравствулте мир' for example.

**iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string**. If I use the KOI8-U encoding it get does not fail but this is what it prints on the pdf 'úÄÒÁ×ÓÔ×ÕÌÔÅ ÍÉÒ'

Comment: I had same problem and have to spend few days to solve it. I understand you. Just follow the way I wrote. First you need font that contains your encoding. Do u installed new font?